# Configure Google Crashlytics using a sedond firebase profile

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Is there any way to have a separate google firebase profile just for analytics/crashlytics? Currently in the application that I am working there is a firebase configuration file (google-services.json) which is being used for push notifications.

Due to some reasons though, now that the crashlytics are on firebase, I do not want to use the push notification account but initialize crashlytics with a separate one.

Firebase Profile 1: Push notifications

Firebase Profile 2: Crashlytics

The only info I have found regarding that is from the official documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) but I have not still found how to feed this FirebaseApp to crashlytics.

Comment: As far as I know, both Crashlytics and FCM can only use a single, default FirebaseApp to operate.

Comment: @DougStevenson that is unfortunate, thanks for your answer though.